# Completeness character is an invariant by isometries

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, isometry

Let be $(M,g)$ a connected Riemannian manifold which is complete. Is it true that if $(M',g')$ is isometric to $(M,g)$, then $(M',g')$ is complete?

Comment: Yes,  and you can show this thanks to Hopf-Rinow thoerem, for example.

Comment: It suffices to show that any constant speed geodesic segment in $M'$ can be extended to a complete one. If $u: M' \rightarrow M$ is an isometry, and $c: (a,b) \rightarrow M'$ is a constant speed geodesic, than $u\circ c: (a,b) \rightarrow M$ is a constant speed geodesic, which can be extended to a constant speed geodesic $\hat{c}: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow M$. Then $u^{-1}\circ\hat{c}: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow M$ is a constant speed geodesic in $M'$ that extends $c$.